# How to display a list of all currently running and exited docker containers in a html page?

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu

I want to create a container admin panel using node js. So its basically a page where a user should be able to see the list of all currently running and exited docker containers/images, which is similar to the output of the 'docker ps -a' command. Then Next to each container name, I will create 2 buttons to deploy or decommission that container.

Currently, I have only created 2 buttons to deploy and decommission a particular/specific tomcat container. But what I want is a list of all running docker images/containers along with their status(up or exited) in a table format. I am not really sure about how and where I will get this information. My guess is that I will have to save the output of the 'docker ps -a' command in some JSON file or array, iterate it and append those values onto the HTML page.

my current node js code that deploys a tomcat container/pod or deletes all running pods

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const process = require("child_process");
const path = require("path");

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/index.html"));
});
app.post("/createContainer", (req, res) => {
  process.exec("kubectl apply -f tomcat.yaml", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("\n" + stderr);
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      console.log(stdout);
      res.send(stdout);
    }
  });
});


app.post("/deleteContainer", (req, res) => {
  process.exec("kubectl delete pods,services,deployments,pvc,pv --all", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("\n" + stderr);
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      console.log(stdout);
      res.send(stdout);
    }
  });
});


app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log("Listening on port 8080!");
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <h3>Example of a Deploy And Decommission Button</h3>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Deploy</button>
    <button onclick="deleteFunction()">Decommission</button>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        $.post("/createContainer").done(data => {
          console.log("container created");
          console.log(data);
        });
      }

     function deleteFunction() {
        $.post("/deleteContainer").done(data => {
          console.log("container deleted");
          console.log(data);
        });
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Currently, both the buttons work as expected.But how do I modify my code accordingly to retrieve and display the list of containers with the buttons placed next to them.Kindly help

Comment: Is this a Kubernetes question, or a Docker question?  Have you looked at the relevant REST API and the Node client libraries (both Kubernetes and Docker have them)?

Comment: I think it's more of a UI question on how to show the containers along with the buttons. 
@Vignesh Swaminathan If you can elaborate more that would be great.

Comment: yes its a UI question.I just want to know how i can retrieve and list all images/container available in the clusture in html table format in the front end

Comment: i know kubectl get pods --all-namespaces will list them but how can i retrieve this data and append them to the html table in the front end

Comment: You could just use the Kubernetes REST API:https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/